# What should I do in order to succesfully link a C++ Builder 6 project in C++ Builder 2009 without unresolved external references to CodeGuard things?

Tags: linker, c++builder, c++builder-2009, codeguard

Here's what I did:

1. I've opened a C++ Builder 6 - project in C++ Builder 2009.
2. Auto-converted it to a C++ Builder 2009 project.
3. Told it (*C++ Builder 2009*) to build everything.

Here's what *it* did:

1. Successfully compiled everything.
2. Failed to complete ILINK32, exiting with

   ```
   "Error: Unresolved external '_CG_DESC' referenced from MyProjectsFirstFile.obj".
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a Code Guard error.  Try deleting all the object (.obj) files and rebuilding the entire project.

If this still does not work, then turn off the Code Guard option in C++Builder 6 and try importing the project again.

You may also want to try the [CodeGear/Embarcadero Discussion Forums](https://forums.codegear.com/category.jspa?categoryID=8).

Reference:
https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=52470&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Never let the IDE auto-upgrade a project from an old version.  It never works correctly.  Instead, always create a new project fresh and add your existing source files to it as needed.